# DNS: can't dig 8.8.8.8 directly

Tags: dns, tcp, ubuntu-12.10, udp

```
me@ubuntu:# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

me@ubuntu:# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com +tcp
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60080
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.93
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.104
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.113
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.98
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.114
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.84
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.119
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.109
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.89
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.88
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.108
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.99
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.118
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.94
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.103
google.com.     300 IN  A   46.28.247.123

;; Query time: 33 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue May  7 22:51:45 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 295
```

and:

```
me@ubuntu:# dig google.com +tcp
;; Connection to 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) for google.com failed: connection refused.

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> google.com +tcp
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 51835
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May  7 22:52:06 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 28

me@ubuntu:# dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13226
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 16, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.93
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.104
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.113
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.98
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.114
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.84
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.119
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.109
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.89
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.88
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.108
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.99
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.118
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.94
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.103
google.com.     268 IN  A   46.28.247.123

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May  7 22:52:17 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 295
```

**question:
what can I do, check?**

Answer (score 1):

Would seem that your access to port 53 outside the LAN has been blocked - not unusual on a corporate network.

Comment: this is my private network, on windows on same network nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8 works fine

Comment: and wireshark shows that nslookup google.com 192.168.1.1 goes to NetGear on port 53 and I get response

Comment: then more likely a security issue. is the firewall on?